# Spring Data JPA Specification for a OneToMany Relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a problem with getting List entity Categories using Spring data JPA specifications. I need to get all Categories with their Recipes where `Recipe.dateModified` greater then some date. I don't know how to create my Predicate which would fill `Collection<Recipe>` in each category only those recipes that greater than this date.

```
@Entity    
public class Category {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    private Collection<Recipe> recipes;
}

@Entity
public class Recipe {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    private Timestamp dateModified;

}
```

In `CategoryService` I getting `List<Category>` using Specification:

```
@Service   
public class CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public List<Category> findAll(Date date) {
        return categoryRepository.findAll(where(byDateModified(date)));
    }

}
```

I would write Specification like this, but this does not working.

```
public class RecipeSpec {

    public static Specification<Category> byDateModified(Date date) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            final Join<Category, Recipe> recipe = root.join(Category_.recipes, JoinType.LEFT);
            return builder.greaterThan(recipe.get(Recipe_.dateModified), date);
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
  public class RecipeSpec {

     public static Specification<Category> byDateModified(Date date) {
       return new Specification<Category>() {

        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Category> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            final Path<Collection<Recipe>> recipes = root.get(Recipe_.recipes);
            final Path<Date> dateModified = recipes.get(Recipe_.dateModified);
         return builder.greaterThan(dateModified, date);
        };

    }
```

And also make sure your entities are mapped correctly:

-you are using mappedby but the association is unidirectional!

-The collection must be initialized.

-Use Date (instead of timestamp) and add @Temporal annotation!

```
@Entity    
public class Category {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    //@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categories") 
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryId")
    private Collection<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
}

@Entity
public class Recipe {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateModified;

}
```

Comment: For what this row: `List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();` predicates not used further. In this row: `final Path<Collection<Recipe>> recipes = root.get(Category_.recipes); root.get()` return another type

Answer (score 0):

Inside your CategoryRepository Implementation class, add this method

```
public Category findAll(Date dateModified) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Category> query = builder.createQuery(Category.class);
    Root<Category> category = query.from(Category.class);

    ParameterExpression<Date> dateParam = builder.parameter(Date.class);
    query.select(category).where(builder.greaterThan(category.get(Category_.recipes).get(Recipe_.dateModified), dateParam));

    return em.createQuery(query)
            .setParameter(dateParam, dateModified)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

MetaModel classes are used in code above. If do not have meta model classes generated than add this plugin in pom file to autogenerate metamodel classes..

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>process</id>
       <goals>
         <goal>process</goal>
       </goals>
       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
       <configuration>
         <processors>
           <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
         </processors>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```